# What type of relationship is in this scatter plot

Tags: regression, correlation, descriptive-statistics, scatterplot

[image]

I am plotting the number of accidents happened daily vs the daily precipitation for Car collision data of New York City for the year 2013 using scatter plot. I found a strange chart which I am not able to understand.

Can anyone please tell me what kind of relationship is there among the daily precipitation and daily accidents.

Comment: It may make more sense to plot number of accidents *per car on the road*, as people tend to drive less when there is rain.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I do not have the data containing number of accidents per car

Comment: There might be a non-linear effect of *any* precipitation? Create an indicator for any precipitation over some threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [Matthew](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/97925/matthew-gunn). I'd first look into if there is a correlation of accidents with rain/no rain. Not sure if amount of rain would influence that much.